# Setting Springboot profiles on intellij Idea 2022.* community edition

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-profiles

I have a springboot application recently migrated to spring boot 2.7.0. I am facing a problem on intellij. My application consists of `application-dev.properties` `application-local.properties` ...

Before migration I would edit the run configurations and add `VM option` and give the value `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` and spring would automatically select `application-local properties`. When I try the same with the new version it is no longer working. It always defaults to `application.properties` which holds production config.

while I was checking some threads on stackoverflow they suggested that we should segregate the `application-{env}.properties` based on env and have a default `application.properties` which contains property `spring.profile.active=local`; this works but I want to know if there is a better way to do this by setting up a env variable or `vm option`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ offers a way to set the profile for spring boot app in the run configuration. See below "Active profiles". You can still add environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local`
[image: setting profile]

Comment: Do we have this option on intellij community edition?

Comment: @PhaneeM I don't think so. You have to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of Springboot (2.7.0+) The `application.properties` is selected by default regardless of what VM option is selected.

- We should have environment specific `application.properties`. For example `application-local.properties`
- Create an empty `application.properties` file.
- With this setup spring will select the right `application-{env}.properties` file.

Note: You still need to have the VM argument in the run configurations `-Dspring.profiles.active={env}`